# Data Missing error when logging queried collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble accessing a specific collection in Laravel.
When I log the collection I queried, I get a "Data missing" error.

```
$user = Auth::user();

$chats = $user->chats()->get();
Log::debug($chats); //OK
foreach ($chats as $chat) {
    Log::debug($chat); //OK
    $latestMessage = $chat->messages()->first();
    Log::debug($latestMessage); //Causes crash
}
```

Chats have a one to many relationship with messages.

In the Message.php file

```
public function chat(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Chat');
}
```

In the Chat.php file

```
public function messages(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

The messages table has a column called "chat_id" which is linked to the id column of the chats table.
I think I'm making some simple mistake somewhere but I can't figure out where exactly it is.

EDIT: It appears that this has something to do with the dateformat.

```
protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s.u"
```

And the stack trace says

```
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/next/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(768): Carbon\\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', '2020-01-04 23:2...')
```

Comment: Have you tried `$chat->messages->first();` instead?

Comment: @PtrTon Yes I have. Unfortunately it gives the same outcome.

Comment: And if you replace `->first()` with `->firstOrFail()` to be sure that a message can be found? Does that still give you the error?

Comment: Additionally do you have a stack trace for the error? That might help debugging it

Comment: @PtrTon If I put firstOrFail() it gives me a "method does not exist error"

Comment: `->firstOrFail()` should be called on a querybuilder object, so you'll have to re-add the brackets again on `messages()`

Comment: @PtrTon I will try that. In the meantime, here is the stack trace. https://pastebin.com/1Up4G25n

Comment: @PtrTon I tried `$chat->messages()->firstOrFail()` but it also gave me a data missing error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206476/discussion-between-ptrton-and-marissa).